# Loading elements to a component that get the names from Redux or a Database

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, router, styled-components

I’m trying to show some chechboxes whose names are read from a database

If the names are hardcoded at the beginning of the component, the checkboxes show ok, but, if the names come from redux, they don´t show

I think that the problem resides in that the component is rendered without the names, and when the names are obtained from useSelector (I think it’s async) they don’t show because they are already being rendered without the names.

The same problem happened when I tried to bring the names from a DATABASE, I thought that doing it from Redux, would be better

I'm using React, Router, and Redux (the traditional way, without the toolkit), styled-components and sequelize with postgres

```
function CategoryFilter() { 

    let teaTypeNames = useSelector(state => state.categories) // state.categories is an array of strings
    const dispatch = useDispatch()
    
    useEffect(() => {
        dispatch(showCategories()) // this is an attempt to fix the problem
    }, [])

    … … …

    return (
        <CategoryFilterContainer>// these are styled components

        <CategoryType>Tipo de Té</CategoryType>
        {teaTypes.map((val, i) => {
            return (
                <> 
                    <label for={i} key={i}>
                        <CategoryInput 
                            key={i}
                            name={i}
                            type="checkbox" 
                            checked={val}
                            onChange={(e) => setTeaTypeNewCheckValue(i, e)}
                        />
                        {teaTypeNames[i]}
                    </label>
                </>
            ) 
 }

export default CategoryFilter;
```

What could I be missing here

Thanks in advance

Rafael

Comment: `useSelector` *should* cause the component to re-render when the selected value changes.  Do you know if `state.categories` is being set properly?

Comment: yes, I checked with console.log, and it's ok

Comment: Do you think that I should use useEffect(..., [something]) ?

Comment: it seems that there were some problems with state.categrories, the problem was fixed. Thank you for your answer